# If closed lambda calculus expression $M$ doesn't have a normal form, can $λx.λy.(M (x y))$ have a normal form?

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus

I'm trying to solve the following problem, but I'm not sure if it's actually possible/true:

"Let $M$ be a closed pure lambda term without normal form. Prove that $\lambda x.\lambda y.(M (x y))$ has no normal form either".

The similar problem with $\lambda x.(M x)$ can be proved trivially by eta-reduction; does this automatically imply the proof of my problem?

If $\lambda x.\lambda y.(M (x y))$ *can* have a normal form, can you give a counterexample expression $M$?

Comment: By normal form, do you mean $\beta\eta$-normal form or just $\beta$-normal form? Said differently, what do you consider as a reduction? $\beta$ or $\beta\eta$?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I only meant $\beta$-normal form and $\beta$-reduction. Proofs for $\beta\eta$ would be very similar though, right?

Comment: Do you know something called head $\beta$-reduction $\to_h$? And that if $N \to_\beta^* L$ then $N \to_h^* P \to_{\lnot h}^* L$ for some term $P$ (where $\to_{\lnot h}$ is $\beta$-reduction that is not head)?

Comment: Yes I do know that, how would it help here?